# IE issue with DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I have a AJAX form and I use this line on receiving a response:

```
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Output is a div and in IE I'm getting an Unknown JavaScript Error.

Would it be the content that's being passed from the AJAX that's causing this error or is there something syntactically wrong with that line?

EDIT:

```
if(valid==true){
  //AJAX
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }else{// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
          document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
          id = document.getElementById("parentID").value;
      }
  }
  var parameters = "shedloadofvariables"+shedloadofVariables;

  xmlhttp.open("POST", "register.php", true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.send(parameters);
  }
else{
  alert("Please Fill in All Fields");   
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Why do you think the error is at that line? IE line number tend to be a little off...

Comment: I used the developer tools in IE and they highlighted that line specifically.

Comment: AND I debugged and that's the line the debugger stalled at

Comment: Can you post more code (e.g., the complete callback handler) and the response that gets send?

Comment: It's a huge HTML render, I'll post as much as I can now - give me 5 minutes

Comment: Are you 100% (or maybe 110%) certain that the "output" element is really a `<div>`?  I've seen "Unknown Error" when doing something like trying to set "innerHTML" on a `<style>` element.

Comment: Well, OK, but if it were me I'd sure double-check that the call to "getElementById()" is really returning what you think it is. For example, IE will treat elements with a "name" attribute of "output" as candidates for matching on "id".

Comment: And I assume `parentID` is indeed a form element with a `value` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't understand the problem fully (Andy E's answer certainly helps though).

I found a work-around for this issue:

```
var t = document.createElement('div');
t.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
document.getElementById("output").appendChild(t);
```

Flawless.

Don't know why, but I'm not about to question it, because it works!

Answer (score 3):

> Output is a div and in IE I'm getting an Unknown JavaScript Error.

*"Unknown runtime error"* commonly occurs when setting invalid HTML via the `innerHTML` property.  Not all invalid HTML will cause this problem — the common case is trying to stuff a block element into an element that doesn't allow block elements, like a `<div>` inside a `<p>`.  Only IE spits out this error message, other browsers will do their best to recover from your crappy HTML.

First thing to do is validate the HTML with the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org).  For more information, take a look at http://blog.rakeshpai.me/2007/02/ies-unknown-runtime-error-when-using.html.

Comment: After extensive googling I had a workaround for the problem without editing any of the incoming responseText - See my answer

Comment: I've validated my response text and it's clean... The only error was related to the fact that the form which I was passing in html didn't have an action attribute (it's Javascript powered so the missing action is for a reason)

Answer (score 2):

You could try using jquery `$('#output').html(xmlhttp.responseText);`

Comment: Jquery is just a shorthand way of saying `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML` which didn't work. JQuery doesn't provide any new functionality, it's simply a unique, fun and easier way to do existing things.

Comment: well, I had the same problem as you. And the above fixed it.

Comment: could you explain why it works rather than just stating that it does?